# UIWebView content resize issue in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I have a UIWebview in iPad. I have attached a screens shot. Please see its coordinates and the masking of its position (The web view is added to xib in portrait mode). However when I load that in portrait mode or landscape mode the content is fit to the size of the web view. Issue arise when I turn the iPad to a different orientation. That means even though the UIWebView resizes properly the content doesnt resize properly. As a work around seen in many places I used the following meta tag in the head section of the web page Im loading.

However also used the "webView.scalesPageToFit = YES". Still no luck. Please help me to solve this problem.
[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
   fromInterfaceOrientation
{
   [webView reload];
}
```

Comment: Ya this is an alternative. But every time it loads data from server and as the content is large in my case this is not a good approach. I want to load the data once and do rotation with that loaded data.